# How to bind OrderedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I try to bind an `OrderedDictionary` to a view but when the post method gets invoked the Dictionary is always empty.

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Edit(string username, string password)
    {
        Xml test = new Xml(@"c:\Users\pc\Desktop\xml - Copy.xml");
        XmlNode userNode = test.GetUserNodeByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
        User user = new User();
        user.BindData(userNode);
        return View(user.user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Edit(OrderedDictionary attributes)
    {
        return View(attributes);
    }
```

And here is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Users")) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>

    @{int counter = 0;}
    @{string name = "";}
    @foreach (DictionaryEntry attribute in Model)
    {
        { name = "[" + counter + "].key"; }
        <input type="hidden" name=@name value=@attribute.Key />
        @attribute.Key @Html.TextBoxFor(m => attribute.Value)
        counter++;
        <br />
    }
</fieldset>
}
```

And the result Html looks like this is:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Username" name="[0].key">
  Username
  <input id="attribute_Value" type="text" value="Anamana" name="attribute.Value">
```

So the content of the `OrderedDictionary` appears fine in the view but when I make a post back the binding isn't working and the directory remains empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meantime I have found the solution.

I can pass an `OrderedDictionary` to the view page.
It process it by the following `Razor` code:

```
    @model System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
    (...)
    @{int counter = 0;}
    @{string name = "";}
    @foreach (DictionaryEntry attribute in Model)
    {
        { name = "[" + counter + "].key"; }
        @Html.Hidden(name, attribute.Key)
        {name = "[" + counter + "].value";}
        @attribute.Key @Html.TextBox(name, attribute.Value)
        counter++;
        <br />
    }
```

The result `HTML`'s structure fits to the samples which is found in a book, the values from the dictionary appears fine on the page.

After POST was invoked the POST handler function gets the modified values in a `Dictionary`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Edit(Dictionary<string, string> attributes)
    {}
```

I don't know why but I can't use `OrderedDictionary` here.

Comment: Nice solution, you could an `OrderedDictionary` but you have to implement a ModelBinder for complex types.

Answer (score 1):

### Concept

To bind a dictionary you have to change the name attribute in the html input tag. Something like this:

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(IDictionary<string, string> attributes) 
{  
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="attributes[0].Key" value="A Key" />
<input type="text" name="attributes[0].Value" value="A Value" />

<input type="text" name="attributes[1].Key" value="B Key" />
<input type="text" name="attributes[1].Value" value="B Value" />
```

The `attributes` name should be before the index `[0]` on ther name attribute, because your action expect it.

### Tips

I would use the `HiddenFor` and `TextBoxFor` HTML Helper of the Asp.Net MVC.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Key)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Value)
```

And it will render in the format that the asp.net mvc will understand and get it working.

For more samples about databind take a look at [this link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Comment: Syntactically the HTML helpers you suggested are not correct and not result the correct HTML structure for binding. But the parameter list of the HttpPost handler function is useful. Thank!

Comment: Using `Html.HiddenFor()` would be a nice solution, because it will resolve the name attributes in your inputs in asp.net mvc rules to create a nice bind.